# Mongoose, Promises, and a Loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am attempting to retrieve distinct data based on keys.
First my Schema:

```js
    var SampleSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        name: {type: String, index: true},
        _atId: {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: atHandler.ArrayTypes.Schema, index: true},
        factors: [{
            key: {type: String, index: true},
            value: {type: String, index: true}
        }]
    });
```

For a Sample stored, there will be 0 to many factors. I have a use case where I need to retrieve all keys distinct and for each key, get its distinct values.

A desired result would look like:

```
    {
        [
            { key: 'key1', values: [values] },
            { key: 'key2', values: [values] },
        ]
    }
```

Either doing this in Mongoose (preferred) or combination of mongoose/nodejs would be very helpful.

I have tried:

- Promise.all()
- mongoose aggregation
- mongoose distinct with query where query was a key

I have search StackOverflow and haven't come across similar questions or those close enough to help me piece together from them...if someone does find some, I would appreciate those too...

---

**EDIT:**
Here is one failed attempt.

```js
        .get('/:sgv/factors', function(req, res){ // get all the factors associated with this SGV since the client cannot work with data from different SGVs
            // need to get distinct factors.key and then for each their collection of distinct values...
            var sgv = sanitize(req.params.sgv);

            log.debug('GET-samples-[%s]-factors', sgv);

            sampleHandler.Samples
                .distinct('factors.key')
                .lean(true)
                .exec()
                .then(function (factors) {
                    function getValuesForKey(key){
                        return sampleHandler.Samples
                            .distinct('factors.value', { 'factors.key': key})
                            .exec()
                            .then(function(results){
                                var p = new Promise(function(fullfill, reject){
                                    fullfill(results);
                                });
                                console.log(results);


                                return p;
                            })
                    }
                   function getValuesForKeys(keys){
                       return Promise.all(keys.map(getValuesForKey));
                   }

                    getValuesForKeys(factors)
                        .done(function(results){
                    //        console.log(results);
                            res.status(200).send({keys: keys, values:results});
                        }, function(err){
                            console.log(err);
                            res.status(400).send({err: err});
                        });

                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    console.log('error: ' + err);
                    res.status(400).send({err: err});
                });

        })
```

The results of that is as follows, but also there is a worker died (using cluster). There isn't any stack trace or error messages.

```js
   ['blood','child','father','mother','tumor','433333','4444','4477hhjj','54','555','f2','m2','13','666','m1' ]
[ 'blood', 'child', 'father', 'mother', 'tumor', '433333', '4444', '4477hhjj', '54', '555', 'f2', 'm2', '13', '666', 'm1' ]
[ 'blood', 'child', 'father', 'mother', 'tumor', '433333', '4444', '4477hhjj', '54', '555', 'f2', 'm2' ]
[ 'blood', 'child', 'father', 'mother', 'tumor' ]
[ '433333', '4444', '4477hhjj', '54', '555', 'child', 'f2', 'm2' ]
[ '433333', '4444', '4477hhjj', '54', '555', 'child', 'f2', 'm2' ]
[ '433333', '4444', '4477hhjj', '54', '555', 'child', 'f2', 'm2' ]
[ '433333', '4444', '4477hhjj', '54', '555', 'child', 'f2', 'm2' ]
[ '433333', '4444', '4477hhjj', '54', '555', 'child', 'f2', 'm2', '13', '566', 'm1' ]
```

The keys are: ['f1','f2','f3','f4','f5','f6','f8','joker']
Some above values are somewhat the same for each key. Not all Samples (Schema) have the same number of keys...

I also tried with Promise.all. I am less familiar with promise than I am with nodejs which I must admit, I am still learning.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Just so you know, Mongoose runs in Node.js. They aren't separate environments. Also, it would be helpful if you showed us the code from some of your attempts so we have somewhere to start from and know what hasn't worked for you.

Comment: Thank you for you your suggestions. I understand Mongoose runs inside NodeJs, but wanted to call it out separately because there may be a combination of Mongoose and Promise (which I have also tried...). I will try to get an example of the code up soon. I have tried several different ways and have not kept any of them...see what I can do...

Comment: Promises are just a construct in JavaScript. It's kind of like saying you used objects and Mongoose. It doesn't really mean anything in isolation. Like I said, could you edit your question to show some code from your attempts?

Comment: In the sample output above, there were only 4 samples. Sample 1 had 3 key/value pairs in factors, sample 2 had 4, sample 3, had 8, and sample 4 had 3.

Comment: Playing with mongo shell, it appears distinct doesn't handle sub-document queries. Ex: db.samples.distinct('factors.key', {'factors.key': 'key1'}). This call yields the same results as the same call but with query part removed, which is not what I would expect.

Answer (score 0):

So this is not exactly what I was looking for so if someone else comes up with a better answer, that would be great. If so, I will change the answer to theirs...

```js
        .get('/factors', function(req, res) { // get all the factors associated with this SGV since the client cannot work with data from different SGVs
          // need to get distinct factors.key and then for each their collection of distinct values...
          log.debug('GET-samples-factors');

          sampleHandler.Samples
            .distinct('factors')
            .lean(true)
            .exec()
            .then(function(data) {
              var d = [];
              for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                if (!d[data[i].key]) {
                  d[data[i].key] = new Set();
                }
                d[data[i].key].add(data[i].value);
              }
              var f = [];
              for (var key in d) {
                if (d.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                  f.push({
                    key: key,
                    values: Array.from(d[key])
                  });
                }
              }
              res.json(f);
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
              console.log('error: ' + err);
              res.status(400).send({
                err: err
              });
            });
        })
```

That took the input data from mongo I show above and collapsed it down to the following, but keep in mind I have not fully tested this yet to verify various combinations of same and different values across all samples...:

```js
[{
  "key": "f1",
  "values": ["blood", "tumor", "m2", "13"]
}, {
  "key": "f4",
  "values": ["child"]
}, {
  "key": "f2",
  "values": ["father", "mother", "f2", "m1"]
}, {
  "key": "f3",
  "values": ["mother", "father", "child"]
}, {
  "key": "f7",
  "values": ["433333"]
}, {
  "key": "f5",
  "values": ["4444"]
}, {
  "key": "f8",
  "values": ["4477hhjj"]
}, {
  "key": "f6",
  "values": ["54"]
}, {
  "key": "joker",
  "values": ["555", "666"]
}]
```